# It would be a right way to enqueue the script using foreach loop?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

It would be a right way to enqueue the scripts using foreach loop only for 
`jquery`, `jquery-ui-widge`t, `jquery-UI-accordion`, `jquery-ui-slider`, `jquery-ui-tabs`, `jquery-ui-datepicker`, `Jquery-ui-dialog` and `Jquery-ui-button` because I have to write it many times so

I have make it like this:

```
 $jquery_ui = array(
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui-core',
    'jquery-ui-widget',
    'jquery-ui-accordion',
    'jquery-ui-slider',
    'jquery-ui-tabs',
    'jquery-ui-datepicker',
    'jquery-ui-dialog',
    'jquery-ui-button',
 );

 // Framework JS
foreach ($jquery_ui as $ui) {
    wp_enqueue_script($ui);
}
```

So I just want to know this laziness is a right way or not:)

Comment: Yes. But you don't need to enqueue jquery and -core manually as WordPress has the dependencies set up properly. Just enqueue those you want. And nothing wrong with a foreach here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But to make sure the script has not already been registered or enqueued, use [`wp_script_is()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) as follows:

```
foreach( $jquery_ui as $ui ) {
    if( !wp_script_is( $ui ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( $ui );
    }
}
```

This will prevent conflicts due to another instance of the script being already enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually even easier than that. `wp_enqueue_script()` accepts an array of script handles, so you can simply do this:

```
$jquery_ui = array(
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui-core',
    'jquery-ui-widget',
    'jquery-ui-accordion',
    'jquery-ui-slider',
    'jquery-ui-tabs',
    'jquery-ui-datepicker',
    'jquery-ui-dialog',
    'jquery-ui-button',
 );

wp_enqueue_script( $jquery_ui );
```

There is no need to check whether the script has already been registered using `wp_script_is()`, as `wp_enqueue_script()` handles this for you and will never enqueue the same script (handle) twice. By calling `wp_script_is()` as well, you are performing an identical check twice unnecessarily.